# Prevent jekyll from cleaning up generated JSON file?

Tags: json, ruby, jekyll

I've written a simple plugin that generates a small JSON file

```
module Jekyll

  require 'pathname'
  require 'json'

  class SearchFileGenerator < Generator
     safe true

     def generate(site)
       output = [{"title" => "Test"}]

       path = Pathname.new(site.dest) + "search.json"

       FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(path))
       File.open(path, 'w') do |f|
         f.write("---\nlayout: null\n---\n")
         f.write(output.to_json)
       end
       # 1/0
     end
   end
end
```

But the generated JSON file gets deleted every time Jekyll runs to completion. If I uncomment the division by zero line and cause it to error out, I can see that the `search.json` file is being generated, but it's getting subsequently deleted. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following issue, which suggested adding the file to `keep_files`: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5162 which worked:

The new code seems to avoid `search.json` from getting deleted:

```
module Jekyll

  require 'pathname'
  require 'json'

  class SearchFileGenerator < Generator
     safe true

     def generate(site)
       output = [{"title" => "Test"}]

       path = Pathname.new(site.dest) + "search.json"

       FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(path))
       File.open(path, 'w') do |f|
         f.write("---\nlayout: null\n---\n")
         f.write(output.to_json)
       end
       site.keep_files << "search.json"
     end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your new page to `site.pages` :

```
module Jekyll
  class SearchFileGenerator < Generator
    def generate(site)
      @site  = site
      search = PageWithoutAFile.new(@site, site.source, "/", "search.json")
      search.data["layout"] = nil
      search.content = [{"title" => "Test 32"}].to_json
      @site.pages << search
    end
  end
end
```

Inspired by [jekyll-feed code](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-feed/blob/master/lib/jekyll-feed/generator.rb).